# How can I index a list of data frames by rowname?

Tags: r

I have a list of lists of different length dataframes (list containing lists containing data frames) that contain a row called "net_score" that I want to access. below is an example of a list of the data frames

```
alist <- list(a = as.data.frame(c(1,2,3,7,5,0)),b = as.data.frame(c(4,5,2,5,7,4)))
alist[[1]]
        c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6)
1                        1
2                        2
3                        3
net_score                7
5                        5
6                        0
```

i want to call a row by name (say 4) and get the value (7).
I want to access the net_score in each data frame. I prefer to call it by name but could call it by location (it is always 3 from the bottom/end). I want to sum them up. I have tried using lapply

```
lapply(alist,'[',["net_score",])   #this fails
lapply (alist_of_lists,'[',1) #this works to access my first list in list
#I want
net_score    7
net_score    5
```

but I cannot use it to simply print/output the value I want.

edit: added clarity and example of format

Comment: Can you show an example with `net_score`? And also show expected output. Sidenote: "list" might not be the best name for a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `lapply(list, function(x) x["net_score", ])`

Comment: wow that worked. can you explain how it works?

Comment: lapply takes a list as its first parameter and applies the function in the second parameter on each of the objects in the list. In this case, I created what's called an anonymous function or an inline function. What the function does is take whatever value is passed into it, and return the row called "net_score". So, in total, I took a list and ran an lapply over it with a function that returns the net score for each element within the list.